# PVC behavior with Dynamic Provision and Replicaset

Tags: kubernetes

I  have a question please, for PVC that is bound to one PV through dynamic storageclass on a pod created by a replica set , if that pod gets terminated and restarted on another host will it get the same PV?
what i saw that the Pod could not be rescheduled till the same PV was active but i am not able to understand what should be the standard behavior and how PVC should react differently between replica set and statefulset

Answer (score 3):

another host mean another Kubernetes node?

If POD gets **restarted** or **terminated** and scheduled again on another **node** in that case if PVC and PV exist disk will be mounted to that specific **node** and POD again starts running. Yes here, PVC and PV will be the same but still depends on **Retain** policy.

You can read more about : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#deployments_vs_statefulsets

> PersistentVolumes can have various reclaim policies, including
> "Retain", "Recycle", and "Delete". For dynamically provisioned
> PersistentVolumes, the default reclaim policy is "Delete". This means
> that a dynamically provisioned volume is automatically deleted when a
> user deletes the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim.

read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/

if your pod gets terminated or restarted means you are not deleting the **PVC** in that case PV will be there POD will again get attach to **PVC** and start running on the respective node.

Comment: thank you Harash, what will be the different then please between replicaset vs statefulset please if the same scenario or POD get terminated on one node (actually the node itself become unavailable ) so the POD needs to be reschedule/restarted on a different node , how will the PVC/PV suppose to behave in each replicaset vs statefulset please

Comment: If the node itself becomes unavailable POD will get the schedule to the new node and in that case PV or we can say disk which is attached to the disk will get shifted to a new node automatically and POD will start running automatically for both statefulset & RS. If your node is crashing or unhealthy kubernetes will auto schedule the POD to new node manually rescheduling and restart is not required.

Comment: Thank you Harsh for detailed explantion , just as my head spin around what is then the different between statefulset & RS in the PVC/PV area :) , I thought both treat disks differently but looks they behave the same, is that correct ?

Comment: https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/persistent-volume-claim-for-statefulset-8050e396cc51